# Should a bash function return non-0 on usage?

Tags: bash

When a function or script returns `0`, it indicates that there were no errors.

If a user wants to see the usage of a particular function/script, such as with `foo -h` or `foo --help`, it's common to display a "usage" screen (where it describes parameters and explains how each work), and then exit. In some cases, where parameters are required but none are given, the usage screen is displayed as though `-h` were supplied.

Should functions or scripts return `0` or non-`0` when displaying usage? Is it considered *expected behavior* to show usage (especially if called from within other functions/scripts)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Codepaths displaying usage messages should have a nonzero exit status *if they were called because bad usage was attempted*.

Having that same error when a usage message was explicitly requested is typically just laziness. (At the same time, it's not generally considered harmful, as the intent is for such messages to be parsed by humans, who aren't particularly looking at exit status).

Comment: Additionally, expected usage info should go on stdout while unexpected usage info must be stderr. This is the behavior for everything from GNU `ls` to `python`.